# How to get unique values from each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a data frame, and it looks like this:

```py
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import pandas as pd
    sample = DataFrame([{'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'George','D': 'a'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'George','D': 'b'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'George','D': 'c'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'Genna','D': 'a'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'Genna','D': 'b'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'Eric','C': 'Genna','D': 'c'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'George','D': 'a'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'George','D': 'b'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'George','D': 'c'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'Genna','D': 'a'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'Genna','D': 'b'},
                    {'ID': 'no1', 'B': 'aa','C': 'Genna','D': 'c'},
                    {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Cythina','C': 'Oliver','D': 'x'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Cythina','C': 'Oliver','D': 'y'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Cythina','C': 'Olivia','D': 'x'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Cythina','C': 'Olivia','D': 'y'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Ben','C': 'Oliver','D': 'x'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Ben','C': 'Oliver','D': 'y'},
                     {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Ben','C': 'Olivia','D': 'x'},
                      {'ID': 'no2', 'B': 'Ben','C': 'Olivia','D': 'y'},
                    ])
```

It currently looks like this:

```
    ID  B          C    D
0   no1 Eric    George  a
1   no1 Eric    George  b
2   no1 Eric    George  c
3   no1 Eric    Genna   a
4   no1 Eric    Genna   b
5   no1 Eric    Genna   c
6   no1 aa      George  a
7   no1 aa      George  b
8   no1 aa      George  c
9   no1 aa      Genna   a
10  no1 aa      Genna   b
11  no1 aa      Genna   c
12  no2 Cythina Oliver  x
13  no2 Cythina Oliver  y
14  no2 Cythina Olivia  x
15  no2 Cythina Olivia  y
16  no2 Ben     Oliver  x
17  no2 Ben     Oliver  y
18  no2 Ben     Olivia  x
19  no2 Ben     Olivia  y
```

The BCD column does not have relationship between each column. **I want the unique value for each BCD column and group by ID** -- unique/distinct value in column B, distinct value in column C and distinct value in column D, which will looks like this:

```
     ID B       C       D
0   no1 Eric    George  a
1   no1 aa      Genna   b
2   no1 NULL    NULL    c
3   no2 Cythina Oliver  x
4   no2 Ben     Olivia  y
```

Some IDs may have 13 unique values under B, no value under C, and 5 unique values under D. It does have any routine.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def fn(x):
    b = x['B'].unique()
    c = x['C'].unique()
    d = x['D'].unique()
    return pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(b, c, d), columns=['B', 'C', 'D'])


out = sample.groupby('ID').apply(fn).droplevel(level=1).reset_index()
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    ID        B       C  D
0  no1     Eric  George  a
1  no1       aa   Genna  b
2  no1     None    None  c
3  no2  Cythina  Oliver  x
4  no2      Ben  Olivia  y
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way:

```
(df.set_index('ID')
.where(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: ~x.duplicated()))
.stack()
.to_frame()
.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount())
.set_index('cc',append=True)[0]
.unstack(level=1)
.droplevel(1)
.reset_index())
```

or:

```
(df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x[list('BCD')]
.apply(lambda y: y.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)))
.droplevel(1))
```

or

```
#in this solution, the order is not preserved
df2 = df.groupby('ID').agg(set).stack().map(list)

df2 = (pd.DataFrame(df2.tolist(),index = df2.index)
       .stack()
       .unstack(level=1)
       .droplevel(1))
```

Output:

```
    ID        B       C  D
0  no1     Eric  George  a
1  no1       aa   Genna  b
2  no1      NaN     NaN  c
3  no2  Cythina  Oliver  x
4  no2      Ben  Olivia  y
```